# How do I use discord.py to make a bot that checks through all messages in a certain server channel

Tags: python, discord

I am making a discord bot that checks through all messages in a particular server channel and adds a reaction if the message has certain content. I know how to do the latter btw, but I do not know how to make the bot check through every message in the server. Please tell me how.

Comment: "every message", you mean messages even before bot added/start?

Comment: Yes, I will plug in the bot to my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async for ... in history(*, limit=100, before=None, after=None, around=None, oldest_first=None)`

Returns an AsyncIterator that enables receiving the destination’s message history.

You must have `read_message_history` permissions to use this.

example:
`messages = await channel.history(limit=123).flatten()`
to get channel history messages, into a flatten list

from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel